# Debian local apt repo

Tags: debian, apt, mirror

Using debians ftpsync I've synced amd64 to my local file server, and installed debian over the network using ipxe.

It dawned on me, that the content I've downloaded needs to be shared as an apt repo, in addition to just being rsync'ed. Is this correct?

But here's something I don't get (and I don't have that much experience with apt, so forgive me!)

I have packages containing ansible in my synced folders:

```
./pool/main/a/ansible
./pool/main/a/ansible/ansible-doc_1.4.4+dfsg-1_all.deb
./pool/main/a/ansible/ansible-fireball_1.4.4+dfsg-1_all.deb
./pool/main/a/ansible/ansible_1.4.4+dfsg-1_all.deb
./pool/main/a/ansible/ansible-node-fireball_1.4.4+dfsg-1_all.deb
```

And I have puppet too:

```
./pool/main/p/puppet
./pool/main/p/puppet/puppetmaster-common_2.7.23-1~deb7u3_all.deb
./pool/main/p/puppet/vim-puppet_2.7.23-1~deb7u3_all.deb
./pool/main/p/puppet/puppet-testsuite_2.6.2-5+squeeze9_all.deb
[...]
```

But when I run apt-cache search ansible I get nothing back, where as apt-cache search puppet I get a long list of stuff I can install.

/etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://10.0.4.100/debian wheezy main
deb http://10.0.4.100/debian wheezy-updates main
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no package ansible in wheezy repository

https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=wheezy&keywords=ansible

If you want to install ansible, change your repo to jessie

Comment: Penny dropped. I had a look at Packages.{gz|bz2|xz} for jessie and wheezy, and I'm a tad wiser! Thanks.